# Check when the value in a service has changed

Tags: angular

I have two unrelated components that use a service to communicate data. I am now trying to get the value when the value in the service has changed.

Here is my code

Service

```
public keyboardValue: boolean = false;

public setKeyboardValue() {
  this.keyboardValue = !this.keyboardValue;
}

public getKeyboardValue() {
  return this.keyboardValue;
}
```

Component A

```
isKeyboardActive() {
  this.registrationService.setKeyboardValue();
}

<div (click)="isKeyboardActive()">...</div>
```

Component B - trying to get the changed value here

```
public keyboardValue: boolean = false;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.keyboardValue = this.registrationService.getKeyboardValue();
  console.log(this.keyboardValue);
}
```

How can I get the updated value in component B everytime the user clicks?

Edit:

I now tried the following in my code but still have the issue

Service

```
public keyboardValue: boolean = false;
public keyboardValue$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

public setKeyboardValue() {
  this.keyboardValue = !this.keyboardValue;
  this.keyboardValue$.next(this.keyboardValue);
  console.log(this.keyboardValue);
}

public getKeyboardValue(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.keyboardValue$;
}
```

Component B

//This is not seeing the changes

```
this.registrationService.keyboardValue$.subscribe(data=> {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: This is exactly why Observables are so nice ;-)

Comment: @MikeOne I tried and updated my code but still have the issue. updated in the question

Comment: Please share more of the Service code ... I suspect each component has a different instance of it

Comment: @SiddharthSeth I am only calling this service from one component right now. If it works then I can add to the other components to call it. All other code in my service are not related to this functionality.

Comment: You have comp a and b right? What you have now (with the behaviorSubject) should work fine. If it doesn’t you need to post more complete code (not just parts of services and components, but all of it). Even better, create a stackblitz that shows what doesn’t work well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observables solve the exact problem you are describing:

> "*get the value when the value in the service has changed*"

Here's how to achieve this:

- In your **service**:

  1. expose public observables that emit current value
  2. provide public methods that update state which is then emitted through exposed observables
- In your **components**:

  1. subscribe to observables (*will always receive newest values*)
  2. can call public service methods to cause service state to be updated

When you do this, it doesn't matter what component causes a state change.  The public observables will always emit the most recent value to all consumers.

Here's a basic service with one public observable and one public method to toggle the value:

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class SharedService {

  private toggleKeyboardValue$ = new BehaviorSubject<void>(null);

  public keyboardValue$ = this.toggleKeyboardValue$.pipe(
    scan(previous => !previous, false)
  );

  public toggleKeyboardValue() {
    this.toggleKeyboardValue$.next();
  }

}
```

The exact implementation isn't as pertinent to your question, but the main thing is that any component can listen to `keyboardValue$` and always receive updates when that value changes.  And, any component could call `toggleKeyboardValue()` which will cause `keyboardValue$` to emit the updated value.

In the components, we can just define the data as an observable and leverage the [Async Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe#description) in the template.  This way, we don't need to worry about unsubscribing, since the Async Pipe will handle that for us:

ts:

```js
  keyboardValue$ = this.service.keyboardValue$;

  constructor(private service: SharedService) { }

  toggle() {
    this.service.toggleKeyboardValue();
  }
```

html:

```html
  <p> Keyboard Value: {{ keyboardValue$ | async }} </p>

  <button (click)="toggle()"> Toggle Keyboard Value </button>
```

Here's a little [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-71752886?file=src%2Fapp%2Fshared.service.ts)